# Reorder column, Resize column, Hide/Show columns events

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a `wxDataViewCtrl`. 
I am performing the following actions:

- Reorder column using mouse drag&drop
- Resize column using mouse drag&drop
- Hide and Show column by calling `wxDataViewColumn::ChangeFlag(wxDATAVIEW_COL_HIDDEN, true)` and 
  `wxDataViewColumn::ChangeFlag(wxDATAVIEW_COL_HIDDEN, false)`

Here I want to get notify above actions via wx events.
My requirement is to record all above actions by the user.

I did not find any `wxDataViewEvent` for this purpose, that I can handle.

I found only wxEVT_DATAVIEW_COLUMN_REORDERED and this is also not getting fired.

Please help me out.

Comment: I feel no one using wxWidgets now :(